# Django - Authentication credentials were not provided for magiclink

Tags: django, authentication, token

I am trying to create authenticaiton sytem where a user can loging using a magic link.
i am usign a custom user mode.

```
class UserAuthView(CreateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    serializer_class = TestUserListSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedTestUserPermissionAdmin,)

    def post(self, request, name, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data, context={'request': request}
        )

        if serializer.is_valid():
            email_id = serializer.validated_data['email']

            try:
                user = TestUser.objects.filter(email=email_id).first()

                if user:
                    company = str(user.company)
                    user_id = user.id

                    # Add the random string here
                    random_string = get_random_string(16)
                    request.session["login_state"] = random_string
                    token = signing.dumps({"email": email_id, "login_state": random_string})
                    qs = urlencode({'token': token})
                    magic_link = request.build_absolute_uri(
                        location=reverse('api-magiclink'),
                    ) + f"?{qs}"

                    return Response({
                        'success': True,
                        'message': 'magiclink created .',
                        'data': {
                            'access_token': magic_link,
                        }
                    })
                else:
                    return Response({
                        'message': 'User does not exist',
                    })
            except TestUser.DoesNotExist:
                return Response({
                    'message': 'Unable to login user'
                })
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Then tryin to validate this using the following code

```
class PartnerUserMagicLink(CreateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedTestUserPermissionAdmin,)

    def get(self, request, token, **kwargs):
        token = request.GET.get("token")
        if not token:
            # Go back to main page; alternatively show an error page
            return redirect("/")

        # Max age of 15 minutes
        data = signing.loads(token, max_age=900)
        email = data.get("email")

        if not email:
            return redirect("/")

        user = TestUser.objects.filter(username=email, is_active=True).first()

        if not user:
            # user does not exist or is inactive
            return redirect("/")

        # validate token and check for expiry; we want to make sure
        # it's only been generated since the last login
        delta = timezone.now() - user.last_login

        try:
            data = signing.loads(token, max_age=delta)
        except signing.SignatureExpired:
            # signature expired, redirect to main page or show error page.
            return redirect("/")

        # Check for the random string
        login_state = data.get("login_state")
        session_login_state = request.session.get("login_state")

        if not login_state or not session_login_state:
            return redirect("/")

        if login_state != session_login_state:
            return redirect("/")

        # Everything checks out, log the user in and redirect to dashboard!
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("/dashboard/")
```

I am getting Unauthorized: /v1/magiclink . Can anyone help please?
My url with token looks like  http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/magiclink?token= XXX

Comment: If you're doing authentication via magic link, then I guess you don't need the `permission_classes` attribute since this endpoint should be publicly available.

Comment: Thanks.  permission_classes = [AllowAny] solved the issue.